# How to show IDs which are in ready status within certain time range

Tags: frontend, reporting, qliksense

I'm pretty new Qlik Sense user, and I'm making pivot table which shows those patients who have been in ready status between selected time range. I have columns OWNER_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME & STATUS. START_TIME & END_TIME are in hours, for example, 6 which means 6 o'clock.

```
OWNER_ID
```

column contains those patients who have "ready status".

For now my time selection is made with filter pane and you can select "0-2 o'clock", 3-5 o'clock", "6-8 o'clock" et cetera. When I select a time range, for example 6-8 o'clock, pivot table shows those patients whose start time is 6, 7 or 8, but it should show those who have been in ready status between 6 and 8 o'clock.

I have tried aggr() chart function like

```
=aggr(max({1<END_TIME={">=$(=min(EHour))"}>} END_TIME),END-TIME)
```

within Data -> Dimensions -> END_TIME -> Field, but that doesn't work - pivot table shows OWNER_IDs whose END_TIME is greater than given time range.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me if you had a data table that looked like this:

| OWNER_ID | START_TIME | END_TIME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 05:00 | 10:00 | Ready |
| 002 | 09:00 | 13:00 | Not Ready |
| 003 | 21:00 | 00:00 | Not Ready |
| 004 | 10:00 | 11:00 | Ready |
| 005 | 09:00 | 12:00 | Ready |

...and then a table with the hours information:

| START_TIME | ETIME | EHOUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 01:00 | 0-2 o'clock |
| 01:00 | 02:00 | 0-2 o'clock |
| 02:00 | 03:00 | 0-2 o'clock |
| 03:00 | 04:00 | 3-5 o'clock |
| 04:00 | 05:00 | 3-5 o'clock |
| 05:00 | 06:00 | 3-5 o'clock |
| 06:00 | 07:00 | 6-8 o'clock |
| 07:00 | 08:00 | 6-8 o'clock |
| 08:00 | 09:00 | 6-8 o'clock |
| 09:00 | 10:00 | 9-11 o'clock |
| 10:00 | 11:00 | 9-11 o'clock |
| 11:00 | 12:00 | 9-11 o'clock |
| 12:00 | 13:00 | 12-14 o'clock |
| 13:00 | 14:00 | 12-14 o'clock |
| 14:00 | 15:00 | 12-14 o'clock |
| 15:00 | 16:00 | 15-17 o'clock |
| 16:00 | 17:00 | 15-17 o'clock |
| 17:00 | 18:00 | 15-17 o'clock |
| 18:00 | 19:00 | 18-20 o'clock |
| 19:00 | 20:00 | 18-20 o'clock |
| 20:00 | 21:00 | 18-20 o'clock |
| 21:00 | 22:00 | 21-23 o'clock |
| 22:00 | 23:00 | 21-23 o'clock |
| 23:00 | 00:00 | 21-23 o'clock |

...then you'd have an association between [START_TIME] and [EHOUR], such when you select [EHOUR], it correctly filters your data by the [START_TIME]. Then, you only have to adjust your Set Expression, which I think should look more like this:

`Only({<STATUS={'Ready'}>} STATUS)`

Here's a screenshot GIF of how it looks for me:

[image: Screenshot GIF of my working pivot table]

Hopefully I understood that correctly!